# Rails has_many through filtered associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to use one join model for two separate but very similar associations.  Here is what I have:

Two primary models:  Package, Size

Pacakges have many sizes but there's a wrinkle.  The sizes need to be allocated as a size for top or bottom.  My current associations on Package are:

```
has_many :package_sizes
has_many :sizes, :through => :package_sizes
has_many :bottoms_sizes, :through => :package_sizes, :scope => {:package_sizes => {:bodylocation => "B"}}, :source => :size
has_many :tops_sizes, :through => :package_sizes, :scope => {:package_sizes => {:bodylocation => "T"}}, :source => :size
```

PackageSize is a join model with:   size_id  |  package_id  |  bodylocation:string

I have a failing test to verify it is working:

```
@p = Package.new
@size1 = Size.first
@p.tops_sizes << @size1
@p.save
@p.reload
@p.tops_sizes.should include(@size1)
```

This should work properly but for some reason the bodylocation field does not get automatically set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating two separate through associations for this.

```
has_many :bottom_package_sizes, :class_name => 'PackageSize', :conditions => {:bodylocation => 'B'}
has_many :top_package_sizes, :class_name => 'PackageSize', :conditions => {:bodylocation => 'T'}
has_many :bottom_sizes, :through => :bottom_package_sizes
has_many :top_sizes, :through => :top_package_sizes
```

Answer (score 2):

There is (IMHO) a better solution to this in the answer to: [Scope with join on :has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association).

Essentially it would be something like:

```
has_many :package_sizes
has_many :sizes, :through => :package_sizes do
  def tops
    where("package_sizes.bodylocation = 'T'")
  end
  def bottoms
    where("package_sizes.bodylocation = 'B'")
  end
end
```

You would then query for them like:

```
@p.sizes.tops
```