# Rails: referencing join table properties in has_many :through relationship in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got three models:

```
class Registry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registry_item
  has_many :item, :through => :registry_item
end  

class RegistryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registry
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

`RegistryItem` has the boolean property `purchased`.

```
<% @registry.item.each do |item| %>
  <div>
    <h4><%= item.title %></h4>
    <p><%= item.description %></p>
    # Here, I'd like to display "PURCHASED" if 
    # the registry_item's purchased property is true
    <% if [?] %>PURCHASED<% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'd really like to somehow reference the `purchased` property in `[?]` -- but it's a property of the `registry_item` -- not the `registry` or the `item`.

One way to go about this would be to iterate through the join model objects instead:

```
<h2>Items</h2>
<% @registry.registry_item.each do |item| %>
  <div>
    <h4><%= registry_item.item.title %></h4>
    <p><%= registry_item.item.description %></p>
    <% if registry_item.purchased %>PURCHASED<% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Another would be to define a `purchased?` function on the `registry`, which takes an `item` parameter.

```
<h2>Items</h2>
<% @registry.item.each do |item| %>
  <div>
    <h4><%= item.title %></h4>
    <p><%= item.description %></p>
    <% if @registry.item_purchased(item)? %>PURCHASED<% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm left thinking there must be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please notice that when you have a has_many relationship, you should use plural :

```
has_many :registry_items
```

Now, i assume that you want to have an Item,a Registry and a RegisteredItem class.This would require a has_many through association like :

```
class Registry < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :items, :through => :registered_items 
end
```

If you do that, you can now have a register object and do something like:

```
registry.items.each do |i|
  if i.registered_item.status == 'registered'
     whatever....
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the naming convention assistance.  Since there's a one to many relationship between registry and registry_item and a many to one relationship between registry_item and item, this won't work.  Sounds like I might end up just iterating through registry_items instead of items directly.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the join model objects is clean.

Comment: Fair enough, and I'll go with it if Rails doesn't support accessing the model object that formed the relationship from the "destination" object.

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar was discussed here and there's a nice solution published.

[Scope with join on :has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association)

It's filtering the relation in the database instead of iterating through everything in ruby.