# How to call a scope across a has_many / through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following (on RoR 3.1 and MySQL 5.1):

```
  class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_headers
    has_many :menu_items, :through => :menu_headers
    belongs_to :location      
  end

  class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_tree :parent_id
      has_many :menu_items
      belongs_to :menu
  end

  class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :is_enabled, where(:is_enabled => true)
    belongs_to :menu_header
  end
```

I'd like to be able to call the scope across the relationship; something like this:

```
  # call the scope :is_enabled here
  Menu.find(12).(where menu_items.is_enabled)
```

but not sure how to do this.

I'd like the behavior for:

```
  Menu.find(12)
```

to continue to pull menu_items where is_enabled=false

Any ideas on how to do this?

thx

**edit #1**
added the act_as_tree and location associations as these also need to be working.

Something like this [Scope with join on :has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association) might work but seems a little bit ugly

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Menu.find(12).menu_items.is_enabled
```

It will return all enabled menuitem associated with the menu with id 12.

Comment: Hmm... so that is loading menu_items as a child of menus NOT of menu_headers which is what I want in this case. I do have a relationship of menu_items to menus because in some cases we want to deal with that relathionship. Also, menu_headers are :act_as_tree'd so really looking for ruby-1.9.2-p290 :028 > a.menu_headers[0].children[0].menu_items