# find users where the membership is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user table and an account table. Then I have a account_memberships table this table is a have_many through for users and account. I'm trying to take the current_account and and find all the users who's admin is equal to false. The account_memberships table has the attribute of admin. Anyone know how to query this?

Here is my code.

### Current Method.

```
def account_workers
  users.each do |u|
    member = u.account_memberships.find_by(account_id: self.id)
    member.find_by(admin: false)
  end
end
```

This gives back the error of `undefined method`find_by' for #`

So as a recap: Accounts have_many users through account_memberships. and likewise for users. account_memberships have the attribute of admin as a boolean. How can I find all the users in a particular account that have the account_membership attribute set to false? Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, main problem:

```
member = u.account_memberships.find_by(account_id: self.id)
# returns instance of AccountMembership (not AR relation)

member.find_by(admin: false)
# find_by should not be called on instance of AccountMembership
```

Basically you need to join two tables and query will look like:

```
User.joins(:account_memberships)
    .where('account_memberships.admin': false, 
           'account_memberships.account_id': self.id)
```

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks for the help. How would I call that in my case? Should I make a scope?

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
member.find_by(admin: false)
```

do:

```
member.find_by_admin(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but it still says find_by_admin is undefined.

Comment: @Bitwise, have you checked if `member` has a value on this query? `member = u.account_memberships.find_by(account_id: self.id)`. It will cause `find_by` error if `member` is `nil`

Comment: yes member has a account_membership record of each user

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL or NoSQL? It is not recommended to run query in looping, it will be expensive and greedy resource in big data. Here some my solutions:

**SQL Query**

```
membership_ids = User.joins(:account_memberships).
                      where('...  your users query ...').
                      where('account_memberships.admin' => false).
                      distinct('account_memberships.id')

account_memberships = AccountMembership.where("id IN (?)", membership_ids)
```

**NoSQL Query**

```
user_ids = User.where(...your users query...).distinct(:id)
account_memberships = AccountMembership.in(user_id: user_ids)
```