# Polymorphic has_many_through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have two Rails models and I'd like to have mutliple relations set up between them. I have a table called `Intervention` and a model called `Subject`. I also have a connection model called `InterventionsSubject` that I hoped to use to join the two together. I'd like to link between the two so that interventions have `effective_subjects`, `ineffective_subjects` and `negative_subjects`. My table set up is as follows (simplified for brevity):

```
create_table "interventions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "intro"
  t.text "how"
  t.text "studies"
end

create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
end

create_table "interventions_subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "intervention_id"
  t.bigint "subject_id"
  t.integer "type"
  t.index ["intervention_id"], name: "index_interventions_subjects_on_intervention_id"
  t.index ["subject_id"], name: "index_interventions_subjects_on_subject_id"
end
```

I've tried multiple incantations to set this up, but I can't seem to work out the best way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's actually a polymorphic relationship, unless I'm missing something. Polymorphic relationships allow you to link model X to model Y *or* Z. You don't have a Z here. I think this is just a standard has many through, and you'll have some custom finder scopes for your `effective_interventions` lists.

Comment: I did wonder about that, but thought it might be tricky on creation. Current line of enquiry is Single Table Inheritance, where I have `EffectiveSubject` `IneffectiveSubject` and `NegativeSubject` all inheriting from `Subject` and the following relations:

    class Intervention < ApplicationRecord
      has_many_attached :files
      has_many :interventions_subjects
      has_many :effective_subjects, through: :interventions_subjects
      has_many :ineffective_subjects, through: :interventions_subjects
      has_many :negative_subjects, through: :interventions_subjects
    end

Comment: I can't do code formatting in comments. Hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem for creation - you can create through scoped relationships I think and it will set the right stuff, so you can still have a single Subject model. I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association#9547179 is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making use of rails polymorphic association between interventions and subjects. Make intervention polymorphic table by adding something like subjectable_type and subject_id.
Mention polymorphic association in intervention model -  **belongs_to :subjectable** 
and in subject model **has_many :interventions, as: :subjectable**.
refer for more info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
Hope This helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment above, this isn't actually a polymorphic relationship. I think what you want are scopes, which you can use for both finding and creating objects. Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope, which has lots of examples.

I think you want to add scopes for your `type` field to `intervention_subjects`. Then you should be able to do things like 
`intervention.subjects.effective`.