# How to format fields in a table for has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two models - `User` and `Image`. And also I have a third model - `UsersAndImage`.

There are users. There are images. I want users to be able to add images to themselves. To do this, everything is clearly described in the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

I did it. With this, everything is fine.

But the problem is that I need to add statuses to the `users_and_images` table:

```rb
class UsersAndImage < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    pending: 0,
    active: 1,
    # ...
  }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true

  # ...
end
```

And after that I don't understand how can I further describe the connection in the `User` model. That is, I need to use the status.

The relationship with the table is described as follows:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # ...
    has_many :users_and_images
    has_many :images, through: :users_and_images
    # ...
end
```

And I need to rewrite this relationship so that there is filtering by status from the link table. That is, for example, this code:

```rb
user = User.find(1)
user.images
```

Displayed only images with the status "active".

Tell me, please, how can I implement this?

Now I see only one way - this is to work directly with the `UsersAndImage` model (something like this):

```rb
user = User.find(1)
user.users_and_images.some_scope_with_where.map(&:image)
```

But it seems to me that this is the wrong way.

Maybe I need to do something like this?

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # ...
    has_many :users_and_images, -> { where(status: UsersAndImage.statuses[:active]) }
    has_many :images, through: :users_and_images
    # ...
end
```

And in this case, the change of status should be directly in the `users_and_images` table. But getting the "filtered" `images` will be as usual. And how then to use enum helpers? After all, I want to use them in relation to `images`, not `users_and_images`. And what if I want to get all the images?

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a block to `has_many` block. There is a good answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association). I help add those status methods in `UsersAndImage` in a dry way.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many : users_and_images
  has_many :images, through: : users_and_images do 
    UsersAndImage.statuses.each do |method_name, value|
      define_method(method_name) do 
        where("users_and_images.status = ?", value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can get all images by `user.images`, active images by `user.images.active`, pending images by `user.images.pending`, and other status by `user.images.[other status]`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped solve some of the questions. And what about the helpers from the enum? Any ideas how to check one image - `image.pending_with?(user)`?